# Spring MVC @RequestParam default value not resolved

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have this method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "warehouses/{warehouseId}/issues", headers = BOOTGRID_REQUEST)
public ResponseEntity<BootgridResponse<T>> listWarehouseIssues(
        @PathVariable final long warehouseId,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = ISSUE_STATE_ALL) final String state,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute final BootgridRequest request,
        final BindingResult bindingResult
)
```

Worked great in all cases until I registered a new filter that wraps the request into a wrapper.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(crossScriptingFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registration.setName("XFilter");
    registration.setOrder(1);

    return registration;
}

@Bean
public Filter crossScriptingFilter() {
    return new CrossScriptingFilter();
}
```

Since, the argument "state" is given null when not specified in the request params.

When I remove the filter registration, I get the default value instead of null.

I am missing a piece here, I don't get why the default value wouldn't be given ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had environment issues, other services also had default values but was provided.

After a while, it seems all was back to normal and working again.

This question could also be deleted, since it provides nothing concrete to readers.

Comment: Could you explain what environment issues you had? Other people could have the same problem. My default value doesn't work too, don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "value" property is missing. This value represent the name of the request param:

```
@RequestParam(value = "state", required = false, defaultValue = ISSUE_STATE_ALL) final String state
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I though that if not specified, it took the name of the variable?

Comment: Did not change anything in this case.